# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header | Laravel 10 / Inertia / Vue3

Tags: laravel, http-headers, inertiajs

I have a fresh Laravel 10 installation with Inertia and Vue3. When I call the application in my browser, I receive the following error in Chrome (and same in other browsers):

> Access to script at 'https://sub-a.domain/resources/js/app.js' from origin 'https//:sub-b.domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I checked, the header has indeed not been sent:

[image]

I am calling from one subdaomin to the other. I am struggeling to understand, why the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not sent at all.

If (!) it were sent, the cors middleware config would / should allow this request:

```
'paths' => ['*'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

How can I ensure, that the header is always sent?

Comment: Why are you calling it from one subdomain to another one? Inertia is supposed to have your application bundled and deployed on only one host.

Comment: I am using Codespaces from Github. Codespaces transform ports into subdomains.